# pgRouting with TomTom multiNet

Tags: pgrouting, network, shp2pgsql

I would like to use TomTom multiNet data with pgRouting to create drive time/distance polygons. I have gone through the documentation regarding network topology creation, but am still confused to proceed further. Could anybody help me out with the steps I need to take to make multiNet routable with pgRouting. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Which details confuse you? Afaik MultiNet should contain all the attributes needed for routing.